# DevDemon Updater ajax request error

Tags: ajax, devdemon, devdemon-updater

For a while now I have been unable to use DD Updater because of this error:

```
Warning!
Our test AJAX request failed! We sent an AJAX request to but the response was   invalid.
```

I don't recall if the error started when I upgraded the module or when I moved to a different host, regardless I'm using EE2.5.5 and I have upgraded to the latest version of updater today (3.2.9) with no success. I tried changing several settings and nothing changed, can anyone point me in the right direction?
The ajax response is blank btw.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the exact error message/code you are getting? That might explain what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check if

- URL to the root directory of your site
- URL to your 'themes' folder

is setup correct in *EE > Admin > General Configuration*

If you will not found any error inside this settings, you need to open chrome inspector and check what exactly happens. On tab Network you will able see the ajax request (url & headers) + results. Possible something wrong with your .htaccess and you have multi redirection as example.

For example it is can happen if your CP is on domains with www., but request is going to domain w/o www..

Comment: Thanks, I checked the headers and it was all working as it should, then I realized that I hadn't tried deleting all updater files and re-uploading, I did that and it's working fine now.